# What determines the amount of scaling that results from depth?

Tags: 3d

Consider a frustum where left, right, bottom, top, near, far planes are:

`Frustum(-200,200,-200,200,1,400)`

Essentially our "real world" space in the view is a big cube of 400 units along each side.

I'm trying to understand why, when I translate an object by just 1 unit in the x or y direction, it moves a small amount onscreen, which you'd expect, but if I translate it by just 1 unit down the z axis, the scaling is quite immense. The effect of the depth seems almost way too much exaggerated. It looks like it is "far away" (much smaller) just by moving it 1 or 2 units away.

I have heard of a frustum sometimes called a "zoom lens" for the camera, but in reality, different lenses make the effect of scaling quite different due to depth, but with a frustum, I don't see where you would specify how depth affects the apparent scaling.

I can manipulate the far plane to some other number, but all this seems to do is adjust what gets clipped or not. It does not adjust the degree of the depth affect on scaling.

So again the question is **What determines the amount of scaling that results from depth?**

Comment: Have you considered just looking up how [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_%28graphical%29) works? Following [my tutorial on the subject](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html) has to be easier than fumbling around and asking a narrow question when something doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Hi Nicol, thanks for the tutorial link, I look forward to reading it. I've been reading about how this stuff works, but some books are better than explaining it than others. The concept can be a challenging one to grasp initially, and in this case the readings weren't enough, but getting some insight from experimenting with code and getting some help here and there has been particularly useful. Sorry if it seems like the wrong approach to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined a cube, you have defined a frustum. And it looks like you've created a frustum with a very large field of view, so I might expect that to look a bit odd anyway.

However, what actually determines how something 'scales' when it moves in Z, is the same thing that determines how something apparently scales when it moves toward or away from us in real life. The scale is proportional to how far away something is, and the field of view.

If something is right in front of your face, and you move it a small distance away, it will become apparently much smaller. However if something is far away, and moves that same tiny distance, it will be barely perceptible.

The only real control you have on that effect, is to move things around in depth. So if you want less relative 'scaling' for objects in your scene, you need to move the camera further away. This will make everything smaller, but you can reduce your field of view such that things are 'zoomed'.

The further the camera is from your objects, the more parallel the sides of the frustum become. If the view frustum was not a frustum, but a cube, you would have an orthographic view instead, where depth has no effect on scale at all.

Comment: I didn't show the cube object here, just the frustum. I'm aware that creating a frustum is not the same as creating a cube. As for "large field of view," I'd say that's relative, since the units are arbitrary.

Comment: The values you have given for your frustum would result (if the arguments are basically the same as GL), of a frustum with extremely large field of view. Units may essentially be arbitrary, but angles are not - there's nothing relative about it.

Comment: I see, thanks. So essentially if the near and far planes were both further from the camera I could have more of a "telephoto" effect, whereas now, I've essentially got a "wide angle" effect, since I'm starting at 1 and going out a long way. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The problem is not your near and far planes, but the angles of your left/right/top/bottom. Currently these are almost 180 degrees apart. Leave your near/far alone and set the side planes appropriately. Many people find it more intuitive to use a perspective matrix function, rather than directly constructing the frustum.